# Why does this `grep -o` fail, and how should I work around it?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Given the input

```
echo abc123def | grep -o '[0-9]*'
```

On one computer (with GNU grep  2.5.4), this returns `123`, and on another (with GNU grep 2.5.1) it returns the empty string. Is there some explanation for why grep 2.5.1 fails here, or is it just a bug? I'm using `grep -o` in this way in a bash script that I'd like to be able to run on different computers (which may have different versions of grep). Is there a "right way" to get consistent behavior?

Comment: Why would you want to grep on a regex that can match zero characters, anyway? I would expect it to match every line, not just lines with digits in them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, 2.5.1's `-o` handling was buggy:
  http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-grep@gnu.org/msg00993.html

Grep is probably not the right tool for this; `sed` or `tr` or even `perl` might be better depending on what the actual task is.

Comment: +1: But if there's variation between minor GNU `grep` versions (albeit due to bugs) there's not much chance of finding consistency between different computers. There are plenty of other tools, though.

Comment: Recommending to use an other tool, without a correct solution is not a good answer. As an evidence, in most of the cases it can be solved with the usage of pure bash. You did not include an exact solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the shell. its faster

```
$ str=abc123def
$ echo ${str//[a-z]/}
123
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and found that `egrep` was installed on that machine. A quick solution was using

```
 echo abc123def | egrep -o '[0-9]*'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give similar results:

```
echo abc123def | sed -n 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p'
```

Your question is a near-duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733692/how-to-use-sed-awk-or-gawk-to-print-only-what-is-matched).

Answer (score -1):

Because you are using a regex so you must use either:

1. grep -E
2. egrep (like Sebastian posted).

Good luck!

Comment: -E/egrep is required for *extended* regular expressions; '[0-9]*' is a valid basic regular expression. (The 're' in 'grep' stands for regular expression). Perhaps the bug in 2.5.1 was not present in the extended regular expression support, but the mere fact that a regular expression is used does not mean you need -E.