# How to get fully working grep in git bash (msysgit) on windows?

Tags: grep, git-bash

I would like to use `grep -o`, but in git bash there is no `-o` option. Is there a way to get full working `grep` in git bash, just like it's in linux bash shell?

Comment: `-P` is also missing, unfortunately.

Comment: seems I've got to use both, Cygwin and git bash. but Cygwin sometimes so slow ;(

Answer (score 2):

There is no -o flag for grep
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html

You can use [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736439/why-does-this-grep-o-fail-and-how-should-i-work-around-it) instead

Comment: There is one for [GNU grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#General-Output-Control), but it's a GNU extension.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue for that on Github (even though it's under "nvm"). User [UltCombo](https://github.com/UltCombo) posted a [workaround](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/75#issuecomment-29054164). Quoting:

> Open `<Git install directory>/bin` and overwrite `grep.exe` with a more up to date version. I found two alternatives that provide `-o` support:
>
> - GnuWin32's grep 2.5.4 ([link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/grep/2.5.4/grep-2.5.4-bin.zip/download?use_mirror=iweb)).
> - ezwinports' grep 2.10 ([link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/grep-2.10-w32-bin.zip/download)). Note: You also have to extract `libprce-0.dll` in the same folder as grep.
>
> Though ezwinports' grep port is much more up to date, I can't say whether any of these will cause stability/compatibility issues. I haven't found any issues yet, but use it at your own risk.

<sub>Marking this Community Wiki because it's really somebody else's work.</sub>

Alternatively, get the pretty awesome [MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io/) and enjoy full grep and co.